# dice program not working

Tags: c

So I'm making a dice game where you roll a x amount of die and then the computer rolls the same amount and the player with the highest total wins the round. However I am getting stuck on the loop which asks the player if they want to roll again. No matter what I input it rolls again. I've been stuck on this for a while so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
    /* Easy dice game
    |
    |  The game consists of 7 rounds.
    |  In each round, the computer throws a die, 
    |  then the human throws a die.
    |  The winner of the round is the player who has the highest throw.
    |  In case of a tie, neither player wins.
    |  The winner of the game is the player who has won the most rounds.
    |
    */

    char input[132];   /* user input buffer */

int throwDie()
{
    static int initialized = 0;
    int num;

    if ( !initialized )
    {
        printf("Initializing Die!\n\n");
        srand( time(NULL) );
        initialized = 1;
    }
    num = rand()%6 + 1 ;
    return num;
}

/* Human turn
|
|  This might be mode made interesting in the future.
|
*/
int humanTurn()
{
    int toss;
    toss = throwDie();
    printf("Human throws a %d\n", toss );
    return toss;

}

/* Computer turn
|
|  This might be made more interesting in the future.
|
*/
int computerTurn()
{
    int toss;
    toss = throwDie();
    printf("Computer throws a %d\n", toss );
    return toss;
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int round, humanWins=0, computerWins=0 ;
    int humanToss, computerToss;
    int i = 0, yesorno;
    const int numberOfRounds = 7;
    char ta=0;
    /* Play 13 Rounds */
    for ( round = 1; round<=numberOfRounds; round++ )
    {
        printf("\nRound %d\n\n", round );
        printf("Player's Turn: (hit enter)");
        gets( input ); /* pause for dramatic effect */
        humanToss = humanTurn();
        printf("Do you wish to throw again? [Y or N]");
        ta = getchar();


        while (i == 0)
        {
            if (yesorno = 'Y')
            {
                gets( input );
                humanToss = humanTurn();
                printf("Do you wish to throw again? [Y or N]");
                ta = getchar();

            }
            if(yesorno == 'N')
            {
                i++;
            }
        }




        printf("Computer's Turn: (hit enter)");

        gets( input ); /* pause for dramatic effect */
        computerToss = computerTurn();

        /* Determine Winner of the Round */
        if ( humanToss > computerToss )
        {
            humanWins++;
            printf("\tHuman wins the round.    human: %3d. computer: %3d\n",
                humanWins, computerWins );
        }
        else if ( computerToss > humanToss )
        {
            computerWins++;
            printf("\tComputer wins the round. human:%3d. computer: %3d\n",
                humanWins, computerWins );
        }
        else if ( computerToss == humanToss)
        {
            printf("\tTie.                     human:%3d. computer: %3d\n",
                humanWins, computerWins );
        }
    }

    /* Determine Winner to the Game */
    if ( humanWins > computerWins )
        printf("\n\nWINNER!! The human wins the game!\n");
    else if ( computerWins < humanWins )
        printf("\n\nThe computer wins the game!\n");
    else
        printf("\n\nTie Game!\n");

    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So the dicing isn't relevant to the question?

Comment: You use `yesorno` in your `if` to check if the user wants to roll again but `yesorno` is never set as you do `ta = getchar();`

Comment: Also you are assigning "yesorno" instead of comparint to 'Y'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your program as

```
if (yesorno == 'Y')
```

You are assigning instead of checking for yes.

Answer (score 1):

You're stuck here:

```
while (i == 0)
{
  if (yesorno = 'Y')
  {
     gets( input );
     humanToss = humanTurn();
     printf("Do you wish to throw again? [Y or N]");
     ta = getchar();

  }
  if(yesorno == 'N')
  {
     i++;
  }
}
```

You have your `yesorno` value from previous input; then you receive new input, but variable `yesorno` is the same - you just set variable `ta`
So `yesorno` is always `'Y'`, `i` is always 0 and you're in infinite while-loop.

**edit**
and you're assigning `yesorno` in your if, as second commenter said. but anyway, if you'll write `==` instead of `=`, you'll still be in infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **VERY** big difference between these two lines.
Can you spot it?

```
if (yesorno = 'Y')
if (yesorno == 'N')
```

Also, because you are checking the value of `yesorno`, you should ask yourself:
*"Where am I setting this value?  How am I setting the value?"*